# Distinct values not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

Hi guys I have pulled my hair out trying to figure out why my code is not working. I am trying to get values for different columns on distinct company names. This is what I want it to look like:

[Correct Outcome Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDVBA.png)

But I am getting this view:

[Incorrect Outcome Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpx6L.png)

My code I am using is this:

`IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OutstandingClean') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OutstandingClean PRINT ' DROP TEMP TABLE'
SELECT * INTO #OutstandingClean FROM quality$ PRINT ' INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE'
GO
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [QC Date Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'DATE COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [QC Time Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'TIME COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [CMA Date Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'DATE COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [CMA Time Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'TIME COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [QC Date Only] = LEFT([TSQCApproved],LEN([TSQCApproved])-7)
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [QC Time Only] = right([TSQCApproved],8) PRINT ' UPDATED DATE AND TIME IN TEMP TABLE'
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [CMA Date Only] = LEFT([TSCMAStarted],LEN([TSCMAStarted])-7)
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [CMA Time Only] = right([TSCMAStarted],8) PRINT ' UPDATED DATE AND TIME IN TEMP TABLE'
GO
SELECT distinct FIID,
        (select CONVERT(DECIMAL,(AVG(QualityScore))) from #OutstandingClean WHERE [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
        (select count(distinct KYCRecordName) from #OutstandingClean where (RecordType) IN ('QC') and [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
        (select count(kycrecordname) from #OutstandingClean where [TSCMAStarted] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
        (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean where [ErrorType] in ('Data Input') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ),
        (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean where [ErrorType] in ('Editorial') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ),
        (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean where [ErrorType] in ('Polity') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' )
        from #OutstandingClean
        GROUP BY FIID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This. I did not test the scenario

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OutstandingClean') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OutstandingClean PRINT ' DROP TEMP TABLE'
SELECT * INTO #OutstandingClean FROM quality$ PRINT ' INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE'
GO
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [QC Date Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'DATE COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [QC Time Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'TIME COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [CMA Date Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'DATE COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
ALTER TABLE #OutstandingClean ADD [CMA Time Only] NVARCHAR(255) PRINT 'TIME COLUMN CREATED IN TEMP'
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [QC Date Only] = LEFT([TSQCApproved],LEN([TSQCApproved])-7)
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [QC Time Only] = right([TSQCApproved],8) PRINT ' UPDATED DATE AND TIME IN TEMP TABLE'
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [CMA Date Only] = LEFT([TSCMAStarted],LEN([TSCMAStarted])-7)
GO
UPDATE #OutstandingClean SET [CMA Time Only] = right([TSCMAStarted],8) PRINT ' UPDATED DATE AND TIME IN TEMP TABLE'
GO
SELECT distinct FIID,
        (select CONVERT(DECIMAL,(AVG(QualityScore))) from #OutstandingClean o WHERE o.FIID = #OutstandingClean.FIID AND [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
        (select count(distinct KYCRecordName) from #OutstandingClean WHERE o.FIID = #OutstandingClean.FIID AND (RecordType) IN ('QC') and [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
        (select count(kycrecordname) from #OutstandingClean WHERE o.FIID = #OutstandingClean.FIID AND [TSCMAStarted] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
        (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean WHERE o.FIID = #OutstandingClean.FIID AND [ErrorType] in ('Data Input') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ),
        (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean WHERE o.FIID = #OutstandingClean.FIID AND [ErrorType] in ('Editorial') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ),
        (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean WHERE o.FIID = #OutstandingClean.FIID AND [ErrorType] in ('Polity') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' )
        from #OutstandingClean
        GROUP BY FIID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select statements generate the same data, because the conditions are same

```
(select CONVERT(DECIMAL,(AVG(QualityScore))) from #OutstandingClean WHERE [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
    (select count(distinct KYCRecordName) from #OutstandingClean where (RecordType) IN ('QC') and [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
    (select count(kycrecordname) from #OutstandingClean where [TSCMAStarted] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ) ,
    (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean where [ErrorType] in ('Data Input') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ),
    (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean where [ErrorType] in ('Editorial') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' ),
    (select count(ErrorType) from #OutstandingClean where [ErrorType] in ('Polity') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' )
```

However i recommend you to use Case Statement in your Query, Try this

```
SELECT distinct FIID,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL,(AVG(CASE WHEN [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' THEN QualityScore END))) Qualtity,
    COUNT(distinct (CASE WHEN (RecordType) IN ('QC') and [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' THEN kycrecordname END)) Record_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (RecordType) IN ('QC') and [QC Date Only] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' THEN kycrecordname END) Worked_on,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [ErrorType] in ('Data Input') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' THEN ErrorType END) Data_input,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [ErrorType] in ('Editorial') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' THEN ErrorType END) Editorial,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [ErrorType] in ('Polity') and [ReviewErrorCreateDate] between '4/10/2018' and '4/11/2018' THEN ErrorType END) Policy
    from #OutstandingClean
    GROUP BY FIID;
```